# Rename multiple folders based on a list

Tags: command-line, bash

I want to rename multiple folders which are named as follows:

```
bcf_01_bcr_01
bcf_01_bcr_02
bcf_01_bcr_03
bcf_01_bcr_04
bcf_01_bcr_05
bcf_01_bcr_06
bcf_01_bcr_07
bcf_01_bcr_08
bcf_02_bcr_01
bcf_02_bcr_02
bcf_02_bcr_03
bcf_02_bcr_04
```

And so on. In total I have 96 folders, the last one is:

```
bcf_12_bcr_08
```

Also, I have a list of 96 IDs, one ID per line. The first folder (which is `bcf_01_bcr_01`) must be renamed with the first ID of the list (I have the list in txt format) and the last folder (`bcf_12_bcr_08`) must be renamed with the last ID of the list.

I'm new in bash so any help/idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the "oldnames" appear to be lexically ordered, and assuming that the "newnames" are arranged one per line in a text file (i.e. can't *contain* newlines) then you should be able to use a simple `for` loop / shell glob like

```
for oldname in bcf*/; do 
  IFS= read -r newname || break
  echo mv --no-clobber -- "$oldname" "$newname"
done < list_of_newnames
```

For each `oldname`, this reads a line from file `list_of_newnames` via `stdin` and assigns it to `newname` in order to use it with the subsequent `mv` command. The `|| break` just causes the loop to exit gracefully in the case where `read` fails (because there are fewer lines in `list_of_newnames` than directories matching `bcf*/` for example).

The `IFS=` assignment and `-r` option are probably not essential here but allow `newname`s with backslash characters and possible leading whitespace.

Remove the `echo` once you are satisfied that it is doing the right thing.

Comment: Thanks for your time steeldriver. I was looking at the function of each command since I do not know very well some of them. and I wanted to rectify if I understood well what this code does.

Comment: the for loop record one by one all the folders or files starting with bcf (alphabetically I suppose) in the current directory. The IFS = read -r newname reads and stores line by line the strings in the input newname (I assume that newname is my txt file where all the IDs are). and then with the mv (the no clobber option prevents oversrting) we change each bcf of the "for" for each of the strings obtained and stored in the IFS = read -r newname. am i right ?

Comment: @tucanco yes that's basically correct - I have added some explanation

Comment: Thanks a lot steeldriver, your very kind. The code worked

Comment: clever.........